# Iterate function over all the items in the list

Tags: python

Consider a list with various points

```
l=[(point1,point2),(point3,point4),....,(point 2n-1, point 2n)]
```

now we have a function that calculates the distance between point

```
distance(point1,point2)
```

How to apply the function for all the points in the list?

Comment: I assume you mean `(x1,y1)`. And what result do you expect? A list of distances from the first point to the second, second to the third, etc? Or a total distance between the points in series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

list(starmap(distance, l))
```

or just a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
[distance(*p) for p in l]  # hence the name `starmap`
```

if you are in fact looking for the distances of any pair of points (coordinate pairs), you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import starmap, product

list(starmap(distance, product(l, repeat=2)))
# or
[distance(*points) for points in product(l, repeat=2)]
```

If you don't want to pair points with themselves and don't care about order (after all, "distance" indicates symmetry), use `combinations`:

```
from itertools import starmap, combinations

list(starmap(distance, combinations(l, 2)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the distance be between two points i.e `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`?

Comment: I just noticed that and added a solution. It isn't quite clear from the post, but logically, that makes sense.

Comment: "Product and starmap", awesome combination. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Zip with a sliced list and use list comprehension

```
distances = [distance(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in list(zip(l, l[1:]))]
```

What does `list(zip(l, l[1:]))` do? It combines two adjacent elements

```
>>> l = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]
>>> list(zip(l, l[1:]))
[((0, 1), (1, 2)), ((1, 2), (2, 3)), ((2, 3), (3, 4))]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
result = []

for p1, p2 in l:
    result.append(distance(p1,p2))
```